# Machine Learning - random tree of ferns algorithm

Tags: machine-learning

Could anyone please help me with what is the trade-off between accuracy and numerical precision in the random tree of ferns algorithm. I've been told one can get good accuracy with low numerical precision. Is this true ?

Comment: I am currently working with and implementing Random Ferns. I do not understand the question. Please explain what you mean with low numerical precision? Are you using Random Ferns for Regression? Who told you so? Do you have a reference?